# examples of $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^na_i f_{x_i}^2=0,a_i\neq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Can anyone give some examples of $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^na_i f_{x_i}^2=0,a_i\neq 0$ .Assume $x_i\in \mathbb{R},f\in \mathbb{R}$

Do such functions imply $\sum_{i=1}^n a_if_{x_ix_i}=0$?

Comment: Can the $a_i$ be negative?

Comment: @kccu is. and $a_i$ must have some negative and some positive. Otherwise, the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: For every $x$ for just for some $x?$

Comment: @IgorRivin, for two variables the answer is in [positive to the first question](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde3201.pdf). To the second, neither the hyperbolic case nor the parabolic one seem to have as solution that found for the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function:

$$f(x, y) = (x-y)^2.$$ It satisfies the first condition, with $a_1 = 1, a_2 = -1.$ The second equation is then satisfied. Note that any function of the form $L(\mathbf{x})^k,$ where $L$ is a linear form ($L(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{a},$) satisfies the first equation, and (presumably) not the second.

Comment: I guess $sin(L(x))+cos(L(x))$ also satisfy